# For-if nested in for-if

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-in-loop, for-of-loop

```js
//array

let posts = [{
    text: "First post!",
    id: "p1",
    comments: [{
        id: "c1",
        text: "First comment on first post!"
      },
      {
        id: "c2",
        text: "Second comment on first post!!"
      },
      {
        id: "c3",
        text: "Third comment on first post!!!"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "Aw man, I wanted to be first",
    id: "p2",
    comments: [{
        id: "c4",
        text: "Don't wory second poster, you'll be first one day."
      },
      {
        id: "c5",
        text: "Yeah, believe in yourself!"
      },
      {
        id: "c6",
        text: "Haha second place what a joke."
      }
    ]
  }
]


//loops
const removeComment = function(postId, commentID) {

  for (let post in posts) {
    if (posts[post].id == postId) {

      for (let Comment of posts.comments) {

        if (posts.comments[comment].id == commentID) {

          comment.splice(comment, 1)
        }
      }

    }
  }


}
```

```js
//invoking the function

tweeter.removeComment("p2", "c6")
```

I’m trying to reach a comment (I.e ‘c6’) in a specific post (i.e ‘p2’), and delete it from the array.

In order to go through the Comments objects I wrote a for if nested in for-if;
I don’t get any error, but the first for-if is working fine.
Thanks

Comment: Please do not include code as an image. May you edit the question and include a [mcve]?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I’m new here , sorry for that. I edit my question now. Thanks

Comment: There's a lot close but not exact in your code. Use `for..of` for both of the loops, it makes things simpler. Also, `Array.splice` expects an index as the first argument, you've to keep an index counter for the comments. See a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45xypg1s/1/) doing the job. You also might want to break the loop when a match is found, I'll let you to resolve, how to quit from the outer loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you will need to change in your function. You are using `let post in posts` which gives number in loop so your logic is off when you are trying to access it as object.

```
let Comment of posts.comments
```

You would want to loop through the specific comment with the matching postId.

You are using an undefined `comment`. Check below snippet, run it and edit it as necessary.

```js
let posts = [{
    text: "First post!",
    id: "p1",
    comments: [{
        id: "c1",
        text: "First comment on first post!"
      },
      {
        id: "c2",
        text: "Second comment on first post!!"
      },
      {
        id: "c3",
        text: "Third comment on first post!!!"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "Aw man, I wanted to be first",
    id: "p2",
    comments: [{
        id: "c4",
        text: "Don't wory second poster, you'll be first one day."
      },
      {
        id: "c5",
        text: "Yeah, believe in yourself!"
      },
      {
        id: "c6",
        text: "Haha second place what a joke."
      }
    ]
  }
]


//loops
const removeComment = (postId, commentID)=> {
  for (let post of posts) {
    if (post['id'] == postId) {
      for (let Comment of post.comments) {
        if (Comment['id'] == commentID) {
          post.comments.splice(post.comments.indexOf(Comment),1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
removeComment("p2","c6");
console.log(posts);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it's working as i want now :) 
Just to make it clear, when you write post['id'], you mean this specific id, or the location of it?